# Debian 9 - Cannot use -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED parameters

Tags: debian, kernel, iptables, port

I'm trying to configure port knocking at Debian 9 - everything is configured except holding connection after closing port 22.

When I'm typing

`iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

I got this

`iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.` at output.

uname -a

`Linux doman-inzynierka 4.9.0 #1 SMP Mon Dec 9 19:36:21 MSK 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

It is a VPS with a cp panel - I'm an administartor.

What I read - the issue is about kernel version, but I dunno how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to load the appropriate module:

```
sudo modprobe nf_conntrack
```

Comment: `root@doman-inzynierka:~# sudo modprobe nf_conntrack
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:514 lookup_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/4.9.0/modules.builtin.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.0`

and theres coming an error

Comment: You probably need to ask your VPS provider for help...